# MaxDrawdown in performance analytics giving incorrect value r

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I have tried using the maxdrawdown function from PerformanceAnalytics on a column of returns data and it is giving a slightly incorrect value in some cases (and very incorrect value in others). I have taken the same set of data and calculated a maxdrawdown in excel by calculating the cumulative returns, finding the running maximum returns and then subtracting each days cumulative returns from this running maximum. The maximum value of the resulting column is, as I understand, the maximum drawdown. When using the maxDrawdown function in r I get a sizeable deviation in the larger values of maxdrawdown.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Am I calculating a different drawdown metric in excel? Rounding errors in r? Any ideas would be helpful.

Also is there any way for me to access the base code for the maxDrawdown function to get a better understanding of what it is doing?

Comment: I have more evidence this function is buggy. Just use daily returns of S&P500 from yahoo finance. Calc log return using the `ROC` function in `TTR`. Then `Drawdowns(ret)` shows the top instance is the financial crisis starting on  2007-10-10, which is correct. But S&P500 completely recovered by May 2013. The Drawdowns table says recovery didn't occur until April 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no example to compare the results we can only guess what causes the deviation. Maybe it's because `PerformanceAnalytics` uses "geometric chaining", i.e. `cumprod` instead of `cumsum`?

You can switch to simple chaining using `geometric = FALSE` in `maxDrawdowns` and compare the results.

You can have a look at the code simply by typing `maxDrawdown` and `PerformanceAnalytics:::Drawdowns`.

Comment: I tried switching to geometric = False earlier but it still gave the wrong value. I have sort of fixed the problem by using:

`colMins(as.matrix(cumsum(pdrawdown)-cummax((cumsum(pdrawdown)))))` which is effectively how I calculated the value in excel (pdrawdown is simply returns against date). This gives the same answer as excel. My worry now is that the package is entirely inaccurate and will give incorrect values for the drawdown chart I created with it.

Answer (score 0):

Following code shows the issue with `table.Drawdowns` in `PerformanceAnalytics` package.

```
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
getSymbols("^GSPC", src="yahoo", from="2005-01-01")
ret = ROC(Ad(GSPC), type="continuous")
table.Drawdowns(ret)

        From     Trough         To   Depth Length To Trough Recovery
1 2007-10-10 2009-03-09 2014-04-02 -0.6103   1631       355     1276
2 2020-02-20 2020-03-23       <NA> -0.3610    135        23       NA
3 2018-09-21 2018-12-24 2019-07-01 -0.2025    194        65      129
4 2015-05-22 2016-02-11 2016-07-18 -0.1516    291       183      108
5 2018-01-29 2018-04-02 2018-08-27 -0.1056    147        44      103
```

The first line is the financial crisis. The `From` date is correct, but the `To` is one year too long, as seen in the following graph.

[image]

**CORRECTION:**

When returns are calculated as log difference, ie.

```
ret = log( x[t] / x[t-1] )
```

which corresponds to the "continuous" type in `ROC`, the parameter `geometric` should be set to FALSE,

```
table.Drawdowns(ret, geometric = FALSE)
```

which gives,

```
        From     Trough         To   Depth Length To Trough Recovery
1 2007-10-10 2009-03-09 2013-03-28 -0.7627   1376       355     1021
2 2020-02-20 2020-03-23 2020-08-18 -0.2214    126        23      103
3 2018-09-21 2018-12-24 2019-04-23 -0.1276    146        65       81
4 2015-05-22 2016-02-11 2016-07-11 -0.1084    286       183      103
5 2007-07-20 2007-08-15 2007-10-05 -0.0907     55        19       36
```

The default in `table.Drawdowns` is TRUE. This need to be noted.